# Can anyone explain to me the syntax of the following permissions? What is the difference between the similar ones?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, plugins, permissions, manifest, manifest.json

I analysed various permissions and the following permissions emerged from the manifest. Who can help me understand what they do?

- `*://*/` : Access any URL on any protocol (HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, etc.), on any first-level domain
- `*://*/*` : Access any URL on any protocol (HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, etc.), on any first- and second-level domain
- `*://*/*/*` : Access any URL on any protocol (HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, etc.), on any first, second or third level domain
- `*://*/*/*/*` : Access any URL on any protocol (HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, etc.), on any first, second, third or fourth level domain
- `file:///*` : Allows the extension to access all files on the user's computer without restriction.
- `file:///*/` : The file:///*/ permission allows access to local files within a specific directory on your device
- `file://*` : The file://* permission allows the browser extension to access any file on the user's computer.
- `file://*/*` : La permission file://*/* consente alle estensioni del browser di accederel'accesso ai file all'interno della cartella radice del file system
- `http://*/*` : The http://*/* permission allows extensions to access all HTTP resources (not HTTPS) on all web pages.
- `https://*/*` : The https://*/* permission allows extensions to access all HTTP resources (not HTTPS) on all web pages.
- `https://*/ *` : don't know

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

The third part (path) is effectively ignored in host permissions and is treated as `*`, i.e. access to the entire site is granted.

- `*://*/` = `*://*/*` = `*://*/*/*` = `*://*/*/*/*` = all `http` and `https` sites in Chrome, no other protocols. In Firefox also `ws` and `wss`.
- `file:///` = `file:///*` = `file:///*` = `file:///*/` = `file://*` = `file://*/*` = any file on the computer, however in Chrome the user should explicitly enable file access toggle in the extension's settings in `chrome://extensions` page. In modern Firefox (since 68) an extension can't access file:// URLs at all and the only way to read such a URL is inside the content script that runs in a file:// tab opened by the physical user and not by an extension.
- `http://*/*` = `http://*/` = all `http` sites
- `https://*/*` = `https://*/` = `https://*/ *` = all `https` sites

Documentation:

- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns